# X-Hive XQuery optimization

Tags: xquery

My xquery will search 40,000+ files and check whether a particular request is there or not.

**Example:**

```xquery
declare option xhive:ignore-indexes 'resource-type-index';
    <cards>{

        for $doc in document('/repository/content')[starts-with(xhive:metadata(., 'docato-uri'),'/cards' ) and xhive:metadata(., 'docato-type') = 'XML_RESOURCE_TYPE' and (exists(xhive:metadata(.,'change-request')))]
        return
        for $innerVersionId in xhive:version-ids($doc) 
        let $innerCurrVersion := xhive:version($doc, $innerVersionId )
        let $verid := xhive:metadata($innerCurrVersion , 'docato-version-id')
        let $req := xhive:metadata($innerCurrVersion,'change-request')
        return 
            if (contains(xs:string($req), '1023548')) then
                <card>
                    <comment date="{xhive:metadata($innerCurrVersion, 'docato-checkin-date')}"
                             chgreq="{xhive:metadata($innerCurrVersion ,'change-request')}"
                             wcnum ="{xhive:metadata($innerCurrVersion, 'Workcard Number')}"
                             versionId="{xhive:metadata($innerCurrVersion , 'docato-version-id')}"
                             comment="{xhive:metadata($innerCurrVersion , 'docato-comment')}"/>
                </card>
            else ()
    }</cards>
```

How do I optimize this, since this approach is taking longer time?

Comment: X-Hive was acquired by EMC quite some time ago. If you want performance, you might not want to use an outdated, unspported product, where development has stopped.

Comment: Actually what was X-Hive is alive and well inside EMC's Documentum product suite as XDB. Perhaps a newer version is available to the user?

Comment: Thanks @adamretter, I should have clarified this. I am aware of it, but because of the renaming I suspect a rather outdated version is used here. But this is just speculation, so I think it would be good if the OP clarifies which version is in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that X-Hive, now xDB, is still very much alive as I'm a developer on it ;)

As for your question, there is unfortunately not much you can do. The xDB version you're using only support efficiently querying the latest version of documents, as you're trying to search all versions the engine has no choice but to revert to an exhaustive search.

In xDB 10.4 we introduced a new versioning data format that allows you to efficiently query (and index) all versions of documents and search within date ranges, etc. Unfortunately that would require a data migration, so it's not much use for you at this moment.

The only things you could do in the xDB version that you're using is either limit the amount of 'cards' you're searching through (right now you seem to search through all of them), or somehow expose all your change requests to the latest version of your documents so you can use a traditional index to greatly limit the amount of documents that you have to scan through version-by-version. One way to could do this is to include a metadata field 'change requests' with some kind of whitespace seperated list: '1023548 1239123 3924923 etc' then you could use a full text metadata index (xhive:fts(xhive:metadata(. 'change requests'), '1023548')) to get an initial set of documents that have a match and then perform the query you have on only those documents.

Not at all elegant, but the best I can think of at this moment.